# SQL: returning invalid reviews made for a hotel

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

BOOKING which stores guest_no (guest number), booking_start (start date), booking_end (end date) and hotel_id (hotel number).

REVIEW which stores guest_no (guest number making the review) review_date (date of review), and hotel_id (hotel number being reviewed).

GUEST which stores guest_no (guest number) and guest_name (name of the guest).

HOTEL which stores hotel_id (hotel number) and hotel_name (name of hotel).

I want my query to return all of the reviews that are invalid. An invalid review is one which the date that the review is made is before the booking end date. A review can also be invalid if the guest never stayed in that hotel.

For example, a guest stays in hotel 5 from 1 Jun 2019 to 15 Jun 2019. If the guest makes a review on 14 Jun 2019 it is invalid - the review is also invalid if it is made on 29 May 2019 (before the booking starts). If the guest makes a review for hotel 8 (which they haven't stayed in) the review is also invalid.

This is my code:

```
SELECT
    r.review_id,
    g.guest_no,
    g.guest_name,
    h.hotel_id,
    h.hotel_name,
    r.review_date
FROM
    (((review r
    INNER JOIN
    guest g
    ON
    r.guest_no = g.guest_no)
    INNER JOIN
    hotel h
    ON
    r.hotel_id = h.hotel_id)
    INNER JOIN
    booking b
    ON
    g.guest_no = b.guest_no)
WHERE
    r.review_date < b.booking_start
    OR
    r.review_date BETWEEN b.booking_start AND b.booking_end
    OR
    r.hotel_id != b.hotel_id
ORDER BY
    r.review_date;
```

My query is returning multiples of the same output.

Could somebody please point out the modifications I need to make to my code to achieve the desired output?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're joining to every booking that a guest has ever had, to try to see if a particular review is valid or not. This would flag as invalid every review a guest has ever done for all time if he simply books and stays in a different hotel after making a review.

How long after a person stayed in a hotel do you want to call a new review valid? The right way to do it is to call a review valid if it is within X days of a completed booking for that hotel, NOT if it the review is before a booking for that or any hotel.

```
SELECT
   r.review_id,
   g.guest_no,
   g.guest_name,
   h.hotel_id,
   h.hotel_name,
   r.review_date
FROM
   review r
   INNER JOIN guest g
      ON r.guest_no = g.guest_no
   INNER JOIN hotel h
      ON r.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM
        booking b
      WHERE
        r.guest_no = b.guest_no
        AND r.hotel_id = b.hotel_id
        AND b.booking_end BETWEEN r.review_date - 90 AND r.review_date
   )
ORDER BY
   r.review_date;
```

### [See this working at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7eeb/2)

Comment: inner join hotel will only result to reviews linked to that hotel.

Comment: Right, the asker wants to see what hotel the *review* was for. What does he care what *other* hotels the guest has bookings for? I think that you're a little mixed up, here...

Comment: OP is asking for invalid reviews, not valid one

Comment: @ErikE is correct. The modification gives the desired output.

Comment: ALso @ErikE the SQL Fiddle link is a great help, it really aids in visualising the problem.